# Encrypt function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

The code below is giving an error for `Left(strEncrKey, 8)`. The error says that public property Left has no parameters return.

#### Code

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal strText As String) As String
    Dim strEncrKey As String = "welcome123"
    Dim IV() As Byte = {&H12, &H34, &H56, &H78, &H90, &HAB, &HCD, &HEF}
    Try
        **Dim bykey() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(strEncrKey, 8))**
        Dim InputByteArray() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText)
        Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(bykey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        cs.Write(InputByteArray, 0, InputByteArray.Length)
        cs.FlushFinalBlock()
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try    
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is probably inside a `Form`. Well, `Left` is a property of that form and the compiler things that you mean it (i.e. `Me.Left`).

To disambiguate this you have to use the fully qualified name of the `Left` function – or better, not use it at all (it’s deprecated). Use the `String` class methods instead:

```
Dim bykey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strEncrKey.Substring(0, 8))
```

Notice that I’ve omitted the parentheses and the `As …` on the type declaration. Denoting the type is redundant if you have `Option Strict` and `Option Infer` specified in the project options, which I **highly** recommend.

Comment: `s.Substring(8)` is not the same as `Left(s, 8)` - you want `.Substring(0, 8)`. And there's nothing about deprecation [in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.left.aspx) - indeed, `Left` has the perhaps-nice property of *not* throwing when the string hasn't got aas many characters as are asked for, whereas `Substring(0, 8)` will...

Comment: @AakashM MSDN sucks in this regard, that’s all I can say. Functions such as `Left` aren’t portable since they are omitted from [VB core mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2011/01/10/vb-core-new-compilation-mode-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx) (think Windows Phone 7 etc.) … Microsoft is overly cautious when labelling features as “deprecated” even though they should have been dropped long ago.